# Problem with React + Node + bcrypt (Module not found: Can´t resolve "fs" in \node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bcrypt

I´m new to React and Node, so I´m sorry if I ask something in a wrong way... The thing is that I have a project I just completed and everything works fine, but as I have users registration and login I need to implement bcrypt to be able to hash my passwords and not storing them as plain text obviously.

After I install bcrypt with `npm i bcrypt` and add it with `const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')` I get tons of errors when compiling (116 errors!) but at least they´re mostly the same error but I don´t understand hot to fix it.

Here´s a screenshot (I´m not using webpack, at least I didn´t install it and it´s not in my package.json dependencies).

[image: Can´t resolve path and fs Error]

Comment: Fixed all of them but one:

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>

Comment: Oh okay is it this one you're getting now

Comment: Yes @monim, all fixed but this one I´ll check how to handle this one. 

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are using webpack v5 and there is some breaking changes in this version . you should add to **package.json** this block :

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  }
```

as the error says you have to use **polyfill**  but if you don't want to include it you can   set  `fs`, `os` and `path` to `false`, to  use an empty module instead of including a polyfill for the fs module.

If you use Create React App, you might have to edit your **webpack.config.json** file (the path to it is `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.json`) and add a fallback to your `resolve.fallback` property :

```
resolve: {
      // ...
      fallback: {
        //  add this ️
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false,
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That fixed like 80 of them, and I still have some but basically they´re the same:


Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url'...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mock-aws-s3'...


Should I do the same with all these ones? Adding them on both files?

Comment: Yeah, doing that errors are being fixed... a pain in the ass doing this manually like this but hopefully this will work fine :)

Comment: How about now did it work or they still some errors ?